# Create a logging program

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, process, logging

I want to create a program that logs all the processes started by the user and confirms after they are started. I don't want to log all the syscalls and other daemon processes. I have initially checked out `auditctl` and `ausearch` in `auditd` package and also `acct` but they are very slow and they provide much more information than I need. I want something like `ps` (that reports a snapshot of the current processes).

Currently I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on an AMD X2 and on an Intel dual core. Thanks!

Comment: How about using `ps` then - what doesn't it do that you need?

Comment: I ll be more precise here .
 I just want to put a notification to the user when the program is up and running something like an alert command for every processes.

I am using bash and C/Cpp for the scripting and programming respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify a programming language for your program, i am going to recommend using Python. There are a number of ways to find out the current running processes:

a) Use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess) to call ps and then parse its output. It is not pretty, but [it can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682446/splitting-out-the-output-of-ps-using-python).

b) Use a third party python module like [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) or [psi](http://www.psychofx.com/psi/).

c) Since you use linux, you can [look at the /proc filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703640/process-list-on-linux-via-python):

```
import os
pids= [pid for pid in os.listdir('/proc') if pid.isdigit()]
for pid in pids:
    print open(os.path.join('/proc', pid, 'cmdline'), 'rb').read()
```